# Select all the checkboxes above the current checkbox if selected with shift key pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have many checkboxes in the html body and some checkboxes have a specific css class.

I just want that whenever i select a checkbox with shift key pressed then all the checkboxes ONLY ABOVE the current checkbox and ONLY BELOW a checkbox that is already checked (selected) at some previous event of, corresponding css class checked(selected) in DOM, should get checked (selected) automatically.

Rest all checkboxes should remains unchanged.

Here is what i am trying to do :

html

```
<input type="checkbox" class="select-row"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="select-row"/>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="select-row"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="select-row"/>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="select-row"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="select-row"/>
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="select-row"/>
```

js :

```
$('.select-row').click(function(e){
if ( e && e.originalEvent.type === "click" && e.originalEvent.shiftKey === true) {
    //what to write?
  }
});
```

Here is jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/839pS/8/

How do i do that?

Comment: You can add a class to the shift click check box. Then grab all check boxes and loop through and check them until it finds the check box with the added classes, then breaks the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`.prevUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevUntil/) function to select the previous checkboxes, then do whatever you need to with them (such as set their `checked` property to true):

```
var $previousCheckboxes = $(this).prevUntil(':checked', 'input[type="checkbox"]');
$previousCheckboxes.prop('checked', true);
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/839pS/15/)

I wasn't entirely sure on the exact stopping conditions so I just went for "the first checked checkbox it reaches" for the purposes of the example. After discussion in comments on the question, [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/839pS/17/) is the exact functionality that was required.

Comment: it also include the checkboxes that does NOT corresponds to 'select-row' class. thats i don't want.

Comment: @Koka I wasn't entirely sure on the exact conditions you wanted it to stop on, so I just went for stopping at the first checked checkbox it reached. Just change the first selector if you want to change the condition it stops at.

Comment: thanks for your help .. this is the updated one what i was looking for.. http://jsfiddle.net/839pS/17/

Comment: @Koka If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to totally ignore the checkboxes that don't have the `select-row` class? Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/839pS/18/